# Swift 3: Get an action button to trigger a TableView

Tags: ios, swift, action-button

Good day, I would like a button outside my table view that would trigger showing the table view (TableView text blank at first, then for it to show after I click the action button). All of this happens in the same view controller. This is my code for the TableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return postData2.count
}


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
-> UITableViewCell {

                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell2")

                let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
                label1.text = postData2[indexPath.row]

                return cell!
            }
```

As you can see, I have a label there too for formatting purposes. I don't know if it will affect the triggering of the text. 
Here's the code for my empty action button:

```
@IBAction func button2(_ sender: Any)
    {

    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different ways you can do this. One of the easiest would be to have your table view hidden when you start and then show the table view on the click of the button. Something like:

```
@IBAction func button2(_ sender: Any) {
    tableView.hidden = false
}
```

But the actual implementation might have to differ depending on what else you are trying to achieve. For example, you might want the table view to be always visible but don't want any data displayed there till you tap the button. In that case, you'd have to do something a little bit different.

You can implement a variable to indicate whether you want to display data in the table view or not.

```
var showData = false
```

Then implement the `numberOfRowsInSection` to return the actual number of rows if `showData` is true, otherwise, return 0.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return showData ? <actual row count> : 0
}
```

This way, you can control when data is shown and when it is not. Of course, you'd have to set `showData` to true in your button click method and reload the data. Like this:

```
@IBAction func button2(_ sender: Any) {
    showData = true
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: it's giving me some error when I try to insert "return showData ? <actual row count> : 0" in numberOfRowsInSection like some expected expressions, im not sure if you meant for me to input "Int" in its place or leave it exactly as you wrote. btw I just added my code for numberOfRowsInSection function to my original question in case.

Comment: I wanted you to put the actual number of rows in there - I don't know if you get the number of rows from a variable or if you are hardcoding it in - so I left that value for you to insert whichever way you do it :)

Comment: done. replaced to: " return showData ? Int : 0 " but it tells me: "result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'int.Type' and 'Int'

Comment: `Int` is a data type, not a value. You have to put something like 1 or 10 or 15 - actual values. Or, a variable which contains an Int value. Depending on how you have your code set up and how you want the table view to work.

Comment: Actually, you should put `postData2.count` since that is what you have in your code above.